# visual studio 2003 does not start up after reinstall

Tags: visual-studio-2008, c#

After reinstalling Visual Studio 2003... I launch it and it closes immediately after the dialogue preparing to install.

What could be the problem.. I can not launch Visual studio 2003.

Comment: your question is better suited for superuser.com

Comment: Do you see any errors in your system's event log related to the crash?

Comment: You haven't told us anything. Are you on XP, Vista, or 7? are you running with admin or not? Are there raccoons making gestures outside your office window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade to Visual Studio 2010.

**Update:** 
Sorry, was just trying to make a little joke.  VS 2003 is over 7 years old at this point.  I seriously think it's about time to consider upgrading to a newer IDE.  Both VS 2008 and VS 2010 support multi-targeting which will allow you to code against .NET 2.0, 3.0, 3.5 and 4 (in VS 2010).

Comment: I wish..and I dont appreciate your answer